# ¿Error en formulario ANGULAR 5 en el campo titulo?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

Me da un error en el campo titulo en teoria lo tengo bien pongo el formulario

```
<form (ngSubmit)="crear(a)" #a="ngForm" class="">

<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">User_id</label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" *ngFor="let 
datos of archivo">
  <option>{{datos.user_id}}</option>

</select>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="titulos">Titulo</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" 
[(ngModel)]="archivo.titulo">
</div>
```

Y el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

main.component

```
import { Component,DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginService} from '../api/login/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
templateUrl: './main.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
providers:[LoginService]
})
export class MainComponent {

public archivo; 

public identidad;

public _id;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
public _servicio:LoginService,
public _routes:Router) { 
}

crear(a){

this._servicio.creararchivos(a).subscribe(data =>{

  form.reset();
  this._routes.navigate(['/login']);

}, error =>{
  console.log('error al crear el archivo');

}  
);

}
```

haciendo el modelo como pone abajo me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: coloca el codigo del main component. ahi tienes definido el model? el problema es el modelo archivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe que no has definido tu modelo archivo, un ejemplo:

```
import { Component,DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginService} from '../api/login/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Archivo } from '../model/archivo.model';

@Component({
selector: 'app-main',
templateUrl: './main.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
providers:[LoginService]
})
export class MainComponent {

public archivo: Archivo; 

public identidad;

public _id;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
public _servicio:LoginService,
public _routes:Router) { 
this.archivo = new Archivo('','','');//Puedes inicializar tus columnas para mostrarse al inicio de la carga de tu pagina
}

crear(a){

this._servicio.creararchivos(a).subscribe(data =>{

  form.reset();
  this.archivo = data;
  this._routes.navigate(['/login']);

}, error =>{
  console.log('error al crear el archivo');

}  
);
```

Tienes que tener tu archivo model;

```
 export class Archivo{
        constructor(
            public user_id:number,
            public titulo: string
        ){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Se podria hacer con una interfaz como seria el ejemplo gracias..

Comment: lo acabo de probar y me da error

Comment: Olvide colocar el tipo de variable Archivo: Public archivo: Archivo;